# Encontrar la maxima distancia de Nodos (numeros) en una listaSimple

Tags: java, lista

Estoy realizando un ejercicio que consiste en que debo hallar la máxima distancia entre 2 nodos que en realidad son números contenidos en una listaSimple Recursivamente es decir, adjunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se trata de desarrollar un método recursivo que devuelva un valor entero correspondiente a la máxima distancia, lo que será el resultado del método. El proceso tiene lugar durante la fase de “ida” y no existe posibilidad de terminación anticipada.
Consiste en actualizar maximaDistancia como consecuencia de cada par de apariciones sucesivas de n. Para ello se utiliza un argumento entero (distancia), con valor inicial 0., Para su realización se me dieron algunas observaciones:

Solo se permite la realización de un único recorrido de la lista
No se permite la utilización de ninguna estructura de datos auxiliar.
Se supone que el valor clave x siempre va a existir en la lista.
En caso de que solo se encontrase un único elemento que contiene el valor clave x, se deberá devolver como distancia máxima el valor cero.

El codigo que he realizado hasta el momento y sobre el cual aun no he podido hallar una solución Agradezco la ayuda prestada:

```
public class ejercicio_5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ListaSimple<Integer> lista = new ListaSimple<Integer>();
    int maximaDistancia = 0;

    lista.agregarInicio(9);
    lista.agregarInicio(4);
    lista.agregarInicio(7);
    lista.agregarInicio(1);
    lista.agregarInicio(4);
    Nodo<Integer> nodo = lista.getNodoPrimero();

    System.out.println(buscarMaxDistancia(lista, maximaDistancia, nodo, 4, 0, false));
}

static int buscarMaxDistancia(ListaSimple<Integer> lista, int maximaDistancia, Nodo<Integer> nodo, int x, int i,
        boolean bool) {

    if (nodo != null) {

        if (bool == true && nodo.getValorNodo() == x && i > maximaDistancia) {
            maximaDistancia++;
            //i = 0;
            nodo = nodo.getSiguienteNodo();
            System.out.println("1");
            return buscarMaxDistancia(lista, maximaDistancia, nodo, x, i, false);
        }
        if (nodo.getValorNodo() == x) {
            //i = 0;
            bool = true;
            nodo = nodo.getSiguienteNodo();
            System.out.println("2");
            i++;
            return buscarMaxDistancia(lista, maximaDistancia, nodo, x, i, bool);
        }
        if (nodo.getValorNodo() != x) {
            i++;
            nodo = nodo.getSiguienteNodo();
            System.out.println("3");
            return buscarMaxDistancia(lista, maximaDistancia, nodo, x, i, false);
        }
    }
    return maximaDistancia;
}
```

}

He intentado cambiar las condiciones y permitir de que realice el numero mas de 1 vez, pero el resultado simepre es 0, quizas es porque reinicio el conteo en cada recorrido desde que encuentra X nuevamente?